# How to write unit test for multithreads code in python

Tags: python, multithreading, unit-testing

Say I have a python module (application.py) of some complex business logics with mulithreads or multiprocesses enabled. For example,

application.py

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

class application:

    def __init__(service):
        self.service = service

    def execute():
        pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)
        task1 = pool.apply_async(service.get, "1")
        task2 = pool.apply_async(service.get, "2")
        if task1.successful() and task2.successful():
            return True
```

test_application.py (I'm using mockito library in unittest)

```
class test_application(Unittest.TestCase):

    def test_execute():
        service = mock()
        when(service).get(ANY()).thenReturn(200)
        fakeApplication = application(service=service)

        status = fakeApplication.execute()

        self.assertEquals(True, stautus)
```

I found the test case is failing in the line *if task1.successful() and task2.successful():*

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 605, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "TransactionTest.py", line 69, in test_create_transaction_TT
    actual = application.execute()
  File "/Transaction.py", line 45, in start_transaction
    if task1.successful() and task2.successful():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 631, in successful
    assert self.ready()
AssertionError
```

and I think the execute() method when called by unit test is not actually creating ThreadPool functionality.

Some questions:
 - Is the unittest not using the python's threadpool library? 
 - How should I unit test the application.py without rewriting the code?
 - Any existing python modules for multithreads test?

Comment: Try mocking the smallest component necessary. For example, try just mocking the `get` method of the usual production `service`, if possible. If they're relevant, can you provide tracebacks for the errors you're getting?

Comment: Just added the tracebacks of the errors in the description. I don't understand, my example does mock the get method behavior only